# Django classmethod doesn't have a decorator

Tags: python, django, class-method

I saw a couple of classmethod that doesn't have a decorator @classmethod. What's the reason about it?

https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0/django/db/models/base.py#L320

[image]

https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0/django/db/models/manager.py#L20

[image]

Comment: It is a meta-class, hence the object it deals with is a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The items over which you talk about are used as [*metaclasses* [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses). One could say that a meta-class is the type of the type. If we for example take a look at the [**`ModelBase`** soure code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0/django/db/models/base.py#L71), we see:

> ```
> class ModelBase(type):
>     """Metaclass for all models."""
>     def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
>         super_new = super().__new__
>
>     # …
> ```

It thus inherits from `type`, which is the basic base class of meta-classes.

Here the "self" object is thus the the class itself that is analyzed, updated, etc. While one does not per se needs to use `cls`, it is common that in meta-classes what would be the `self` of an *ordinary* class, is named `cls` in a meta-class definition, to stress the fact that is the class object itself that we are manipulating.